# Adding a Cell in UITableView with Nice Animation

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation

[Here is what we're trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ961.gif)

We try to use https://sociumapp.com/2016/11/23/adding-cell-in-uitableview-with-nice-animation.html but the animation there Appear from nowhere I want kind of pushing from top animation

Comment: In the tutorial they are animating the `alpha`, try to set it's `origin.y` to `- cellHeight` and then animate the transition from `- cellHeight` to `0`.

Comment: Well, what did you try to change in `animateIn(cell:, withDelay:)`? That's where you need to put your animation. You can just play with animation in other part, with simple UIView, and then incoporate it, but try to change your animation there first.